# How to disable theme on audio player - jQuery Mobile & MediaElement

Tags: android, html, audio, jquery-mobile, mediaelement.js

My project has these components:

- jQuery Mobile
- Phone Gap
- JavaScript

I am trying to implement MediaElement to replace standard HTML5 Audio. It does get replaced however I see strange pause/play button because of data-theme I think. See picture below.

I have tried data-theme="none" on the `<div>` that contains  as well as on the  tag itself. But I am unable to control it. How can I change this Round Play/Pause to a normal Play/Pause button?

[image]

Comment: check this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552164/mediaelement-js-play-button-doesnt-work-ok#comment32587736_21552164)

Comment: Thanks @Omar. However, I have already picked up another solution. See my answer below. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer to be quite simple. I did two things:

Added this to the respective : data-enhance="false"

And added this snippet so that the above override could work:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
```

Comment: this will slow down initializing jQM ;) adding `data-role="none"` is easier, cleaner and faster.

Comment: BTW, if that "slowing down" is a few milliseconds at start up only then it might be acceptable. Or are you saying it will slowdown things deeper within the application?

Comment: not only on start-up, on each page created. if your webapp ins't complicated, then its ok.

Comment: This the App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theappcentral.quranforall
I need to replace the Custom Player with MediaElements.
My assumption is that it is not very complex. And I think footer will not reload every time the page is refreshed with new Audio List.

Comment: @Omar Nice Photography & Nice Website, full of facts. Excellent effort :-)

Comment: Thanks, though it's not mine, I'm just spreading the truth ;) If you're using jQM 1.4, you can use external footer/header that will appear in all pages.

Comment: I intend to port my project to JQM 1.4 after the next release. I am hoping that it will make my transition to iOS smooth. Ny project is in PhoneGap.